# error while install sql server 2014,attempted to perform an unauthorized operation?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

When I want to install sql 2014 in windows server 2012 the following error :

> Error : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548757/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-when-executing-sql-server-2019-se

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error while installing sql 2014, i solved it by moving sql 2014 setup to C drive then run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

> SQL Server 2008 R2

I had attempted to perform an unauthorized for this part of installation in windows 8.1 64bit:

> SSISConfigAction_repair_postmsi_Cpu64

Changing installation drive for another drive to C: , solve my problem. Also, I read on another topic, don't close installation panel, because there is a bug while installing SQL Server.

Summary:

1. don't change installation Drive
2. don't close installation panel
3. make sure your source file is fine
4. run Setup as the administrator

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1) So the methodology I used to figure out what was wrong with my system was to use Process Monitor.

I set the filter to listen for processes that contain "Scenario" and processes that contain "SQL".

2) I clicked Retry, and saw an ACCESS_DENIED for HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine.

3) Checked permissions, and ensured that Users have read.  Permissions had been set to deny on them.

Additionally, I have McAfee HIPs running on the server, so I also had an error where HIPs wouldn't allow editing of permissions to the Event Log registry.

So, had to have HIPs disabled temporarily, as well.